# Special characters in Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create table as below,

```
create table "customer`£`s"(customer_id number(10) not null,
UNIT VARCHAR2(50) not null,
city varchar2(50), constraint customers_pk PRIMARY KEY(customer_id));
```

But getting Invalid character error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe your SQL client doesn't support sending special characters

Comment: Why not give the table a sensible name - `customer_pounds`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am working on a data migration activity, where these tables are moved from AS400 databases to Oracle, so need to keep the name as it is.

Comment: Are you sure your client isn't complaining about the semicolon at the end - some don't like seeing a statement separator, depending on how you try to execute it.

Comment: If in fact you determine it's the table name, and not something else (as Alex suggested), you could at least try different names with the back-quote but no pound sign, and with the pound sign but no back quotes - find out WHICH character is being rejected.

Comment: please don't do it, even if you can force it.  You'll be cursed by future developers forever...

Answer (score 0):

We are working on similar projects. I was able to create the table.